# Create table for each parent and columns will be its children

Tags: sql-server

i have table contains parents and child's records and child records link to their parent by parent id column 
what i want to do is to go throw this table hierarchy and create table of each  parent and its children will be columns of the table 
i could go throw this table hierarchy but i do not know how can i create table of each parent ??
i use this query to go throw table hierarchy :

```
with parentsanditschilds(
parentidid,
childname,
childid,
parentname,
depth)
as
(
select 
ComplexType.ParentID,
ComplexType.Name,
ComplexType.ID,
ComplexType.Name,
0
from ComplexType
where ComplexType.ParentID is null

union all

select 
ComplexType.ParentID,
ComplexType.Name,
ComplexType.ID,
parentsanditschilds.childname,
parentsanditschilds.depth+1
from ComplexType
join parentsanditschilds on ComplexType.ParentID=parentsanditschilds.childid
)

select * from parentsanditschilds order by depth
```

So now what should i add to it to create table for each parent and its columns are its children

Comment: use plan text rather than images - its easy to read

Comment: I can't picture what you're trying to do:  "create table of each parent and its children will be columns of the table"?   What does that mean?  Please add an example of desired results to your question.

Comment: if i have three rows first row is animal and other two row are Noflegs and type and last two rows are children of animal and each row has ID and parentid and name so i want the last result to look like table called animal has two columns (Noflegs,name) @TabAlleman

Comment: Do you actually want to create a permanent table in the database, or do you just want a query result that looks like this?

Comment: yes i want to create a permanent table.@TabAlleman